# SQLite - Displaying data from database into alert dialog cuts the message

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alertdialog, stringbuffer

I'm trying to display data from SQLite database into alert dialog using string buffer but when I run the app I got the message without the data from the tables. Here are two methods I used (Users.java) :

```
 public void viewAll() { 
 btn2.setOnClickListener(
 new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor Res = db.getAllData();
        if(Res.getCount() == 0) {
            showMessage("Error" , "nothing found" );
            return;

        } 
         buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 while(Res.moveToNext()) { emailstring = Res.getString(0);
                 passstring = Res.getString(1);
            buffer.append("password : "+ emailstring + "\n");
            buffer.append("email : "+ passstring + "\n\n");
// when I run the app the alert dialog shows "password :" and "email :" just  
        }
     data = buffer.toString();
        showMessage("data", data);  
        } 
 }  );

} 
public void showMessage(String title,String Message)
{ 
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Users.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}

  //getAllData() (in databasehelper.java) :
public Cursor getAllData() { 
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  Cursor Res = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME  , null);
  return Res;
     }
}
```

inserting to the database :

```
 public class Users extends Activity
 {
 EditText user; 
 EditText pass;
 String email;
 String pass2;
 Button btn2;
 Button btn;
 StringBuffer buffer;
 String data;
 String emailstring;
 String passstring;

 DBhelper2 db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user);
    user = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.emailadress);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.passkelme);
     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
      btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    email = user.getText().toString();
    pass2 = pass.getText().toString();
addData();      
viewAll();


} 
public void addData() {
btn.setOnClickListener(     new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     db = new DBhelper2(getApplicationContext());
        if(CheckifEmpty(user) == false && CheckifEmpty(pass) == false ) { 
            if(db.insertusers2(pass2, email) == true)
            {   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data saved succesfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data saved not succesfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }
        if(CheckifEmpty(user) == true || CheckifEmpty(pass) == true ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error you must fill the 2 fields " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }

});
}
```

insert function (databasehelper) :

```
public boolean insertusers2( String P ,String E )
 {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();

contentvalues.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, P);
contentvalues.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, E);
if(db != null) {db.insert("tbldata", null, contentvalues);
return true;
}
return false;

}
```

Comment: Can we see what your app outputs? A screenshot perhaps?

Comment: looks like you simply have a row of empty strings in your database

Comment: http://imgur.com/JQP9hqM output

Comment: I'm sure that I dont have rows of empty string , however I will edit the post and display the code that insert the strings to the database .

Comment: UPDATE : when I changed the "insertuser2" name to another name without numbers the problem solved . thnx any way.